# Efficient way to get a QuerySet of ForeignKeys

Tags: django, django-models

If there was a simple django model with a foreign key to User, as such:

```
Class Office(models.Model):
    name = charfield
    user = foreignkeyfield(User)
```

What is the best way to get a QuerySet of users for an office with the name "foo". Through trial and error, I found this works, but I haven't seen it documented yet:

```
User.objects.filter(office__name="foo")
```

Comment: What is the cardinality here? You will have many offices for each user, or many users for each office? The way you have posted, you can only have one user per office.

Comment: @AugustoMen Not a great example semantically, but you could have multiple entries of office with the name "foo" that point to various users, so a 1:n